# .NET string.Split(string[]) multiple matching logic?

Tags: .net, string, split

Can someone explain the logic that the split method is using here?

Why is it that you can match on a similar pattern multiple times as long as it ends the same but not if it starts the same?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It iterates through each index of the string to be split (or each string to be split on iterations after the first) and, at each index, tries to match an element of the array, in the order in which the elements appear in the array.

In your first example string `"end\n\r\nbegin"` it tries to match (in this order) `"e"`, `"en"` or `"n"`, `"end"` or `"nd"` or `"d"`, `"end\n"` or `"nd\n"` or `"d\n"` or `"\n"`.  It finds a match on this last check, splits the string, and starts again.

On the string `"endNNRRNNbegin"` with possible matches of `{"NN", "NNRR"}` it matches the first occurrence of `"NN"`, producing `"end","RRNNbegin"`.  On the second pass it matches `"NN"` again, producing `"end","RR","begin"`.

If you run this algorithm on the remainder of your examples you will get the same results as the output you show.

For more information read the **Comparison Details** section of the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx).